# Express root route not working in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, .htaccess, express, routes

I created a simple Node application with 5 routes that serve different HTML documents. When running on localhost all routes are working, but when I run the app in production my root route is serving a 404 page, which means the route doesn't exist.

I have set up A2 hosting as instructed in [their guide](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts). You can [test the app here](http://mariojuretic.a2hosted.com/).

I guess the problem is .htaccess file which I have copied from the guide, but I don't understand a single line in there. Here is the code, located in public_html folder:

*app.js*

```
const path = require("path");

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const appRoutes = require("./routes/app");
const errorController = require("./controllers/error");

const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use(appRoutes);
app.use(errorController.get404);

app.listen(40000, () => console.log("Server is up on port 40000!"));
```

*routes/app.js*

```
const express = require("express");

const appController = require("../controllers/app");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", appController.getIndex);
router.get("/work", appController.getWork);
router.get("/services", appController.getServices);
router.get("/blog", appController.getBlog);
router.get("/contact", appController.getContact);

module.exports = router;
```

*controllers/app.js*

```
exports.getIndex = (req, res, next) => {
  res.render("index");
};

exports.getWork = (req, res, next) => {
  res.render("work");
};

exports.getServices = (req, res, next) => {
  res.render("services");
};

exports.getBlog = (req, res, next) => {
  res.render("blog");
};

exports.getContact = (req, res, next) => {
  res.render("contact");
};
```

*controllers/error.js*

```
exports.get404 = (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).render("404");
};
```

*.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:40000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:40000/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: I have set up request logging middleware and it seems the app is making GET requests to `/index.php` instead of `/`. Other GET requests are working well. I have no `index.php` file in `public_html` because it is a Node app. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.htaccess` file was the problem, it works now after adding this at the top:

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Since you can reach [your home page by port 40000](http://mariojuretic.a2hosted.com:40000/), the problem is definitly in the .htaccess file.

Can you try to add a slash to te last rule ?

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:40000/$1 [P,L]
```

or add this before

```
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: I have added a slash and it fixed the home page, but now I get the following error on other routes: The requested URL /work was not found on this server. Adding RewriteBase seems to have no effect at all.

Comment: I have set up request logging middleware and it seems the app is making GET requests to `/index.php` instead of `/`. Other GET requests are working well. I have no `index.php` file in `public_html` because it is a Node app. Does that help?